# Pedigree construction with hermaphrodite?

Tags: r

I am trying to construct a pedigree where founders are both male and female ( hermaphrodites). Therefore, I have some offspring in my pedigree where the same individual is both a dam and a sire.

I have been trying to use the "`Kinship2`" package and "`pedigree`" function in R, but the "`sex`" argument (which is mandatory), will only accept either "`male`", "`female`", "`unknown`", or "`terminated`." I have tried the "`unknown`" option, leaving out the dams, etc, but it will only accept values were offspring have both parents and where both parents are different sexes. Does anyone have a fix to this or can suggest other R based packages for pedigree construction that include hermaphrodites? 
Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'd keep them as opposite sex of their partner, and color them and add a legend.